# Matching and replacing patterns using regex

Tags: java, regex

I want to replace certain single quotes in a string with %27. The single quotes must meet the following conditions

1. the single quote is not at the start of the line.
2. the single quote is not at the end of the line.
3. the single quote is not preceded by a comma.
4. the single quote is not followed by a comma

For example 'a','b'c' would become 'a','b%27c'

How do I do this in java?

Comment: What have you done so far? Do you have a starting point which we can work on and provide insight?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ignoring the reason why you choose regex to do this task, you can use the following regex:

```
"(?<=[^,])'(?=[^,])"
```

Note that this first solution **assumes that the input doesn't contain any new line character**, which makes start and end of a line effectively start and end of the whole string. If the assumption does not apply, i.e. the input contains new line character, please use the second solution.

---

Or a longer version (this **assumes no new line character in your input string**):

```
"(?<!^)(?<!,)'(?!$|,)"
```

I separated the 2 look-behinds, since there is [a bug in Java 1.5 and 1.4.2 that affects look-behind with alternation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14414407/regex-not-working-in-java-1-5/14415651#14415651). If you intend to support only Java 1.6 and above, you can just combine the 2 look-behinds together `(?<!^|,)`.

If you want **beginning of the line** instead of **beginning of the string**, you need to enable `MULTILINE` flag `(?m)`, which makes `^` and `$` matches the start and end of a line, instead of the default start and end of the string. For example:

```
"(?m)(?<!^)(?<!,)'(?!$|,)"
```

Comment: You mean your first expression to be negated, right? `You have (?<=` instead of `?<!`...

Comment: @Floris: No. It has a non-`,`, which means there is a previous character (and thus not beginning of the string), and the preceding character is not `,`.

Comment: OK I guess I didn't realize that the positive lookbehind would not match "no character" (I thought "start of line" is not a comma, so would match). Thanks!

Comment: thanks guys - this is working - it was the ! I was missing

Comment: @RossFarrelly: Please check my latest edit. I don't know whether you want beginning of a line or beginning of a string. They may mean different thing.

Answer (score 1):

Regex using **negative lookahead and lookbehind** would work for you:

```
String repl = "'a','b'c'".replaceAll("(?<!(^|,))'(?!(,|$))", "%27");
// 'a','b%27c'
```

Comment: Might consider breaking into a line that creates / compiles the regex, and one that applies it - for readability if nothing else...